# SQL UPDATE Query - Basic stuff but can't see what's wrong?

Tags: sql

I'm just trying to do an update command with SQL but have never really used it. I currently have the command like this:

```
UPDATE 'assets' SET 'SKU' = "Another",
'Quantity' = "3",
'Description' = "Another thing",
'Value' = "2100",
'Location' = "Acheroon",
'Owner' = "Fergus",
'Image' = "Nope",
'Notes' = "" WHERE 'Index' = "2"
```

I have tried running it both through my PHP layer and straight into the database. What's up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `'` with ` and then `"` with `'`

Try this:

```
UPDATE `assets` 
    SET `SKU` = 'Another',
        `Quantity` = '3',
        `Description` = 'Another thing',
        `Value` = '2100',
        `Location` = 'Acheroon',
        `Owner` = 'Fergus',
        `Image` = 'Nope',
        `Notes` = '' 
  WHERE `Index` = '2'
```

or

```
UPDATE assets 
    SET SKU = 'Another',
        Quantity = '3',
        Description = 'Another thing',
        Value = '2100',
        Location = 'Acheroon',
        Owner = 'Fergus',
        Image = 'Nope',
        Notes = ''
  WHERE `Index` = '2'
```

Comment: +1 Beat me by 14 seconds. With a more thorough answer no less.

Comment: Great! Second one worked fine once index became `'Index'` as it tried to parse as `INDEX`